When a Rollup Summary Field gets updated do they update the parent's last modified date?
I am trying to understand if we can use lastModifiedDate as a marker for updating and syncing rollup fields from salesforce objects?

If the lookup relationship modifies the parent record as a result of recalculation, then the parent's Last Modified Date will be updated. If no changes occur, the last modified date field won't be updated. That said, there's alternative ways to get those changes, such as using the Replication API (also available in REST format) or using Change Data Capture, depending on your specific use case.
